# Maven project depending on a JAR compiled in a different encoding

Tags: java, maven, encoding, maven-3

If my project is compiled with `UTF-8` encoding like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and I have a dependency that was compiled with `cp1252` encoding, what kind of problems could arise? Consider that besides .java files, also there are resource files.

Comment: If you face any problem , then post it here. We cannot predict problems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems, that's just the encoding used when transforming `.java` files into `.class` files - once the classes are compiled the strings are all Unicode internally anyway.

And the encoding you configure for the compiler only relates to the `.java` source files - other resources like `.properties` or `.xml` files that get packed into the JAR could be in different character encodings, the important thing is that the code that loads them must use the correct encoding for each file at runtime.

Comment: but a JAR is not generated from .java files only

Comment: Well, what else do you have in there?

Comment: message resources, Spring application context XMLs, etc

Comment: @cahen yes, but the compiler's `encoding` only applies to the `.java` files.  As far as JAR building is concerned the files being packed into the JAR (compiled `.class` files or resources) are simply binary, and it's up to the app to use the correct encoding _at runtime_ to read resources.  This is independent of which encoding was used to compile the source code.

Comment: @IanRoberts, then my project should be aware of the encoding the dependency was compiled with in case I want to reuse anything that is not .class, is that correct?

Comment: @cahen it's perfectly fine for a project to have its sources in Cp1251, its XML resource files in UTF-8, and its `.properties` files in ISO-8859-1, for example.  When you load a text file at runtime you need to know what encoding _that particular file_ is saved in, which may or may not bear any relation to the encoding you passed to the compiler.

Comment: @IanRoberts could you add your explanation about the resources encoding not being affected so I can mark as the accepted answer?

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez how's that?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully none. The compiled jar file is the same no matter what the source encoding for it was. At least for class files. Text resources may be a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

No problems whatsoever, you have dependencies to jars not to a src, classes in jars use one and the same encoding for string literals - modified UTF-8 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file